# getting frustrated trying to set up pseudo-dist hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have spend the past 8 hours trying to set up my Hadoop cluster, and to be honest, its getting exhausting. Its not just today. Its been a few weeks to be exact. I have tried probably 20-30 different tutorials i acquired on the web, and each time, i get errors towards the end...like SSH connection issues or JVM failure or PATH issues or the worst of all (WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable) ...and many more. All that leading me to reset my VMplayer and reinstall Ubuntu over and over again.

I am working towards the Hadoop Developer certification, and i need hands on experience on everything from MapReduce & Hadoop to the Eco-System(Hive, PIG, etc). The only thing in my way right now is setting up the cluster for practice. I have run out of options

My question is is there any way(easier the better, but any will do) to install Hadoop MapReduce Version 2(YARN) without pulling my hair out? I would really like something that has been shown to be consistent and has worked for multiple people.

64 bit on Ubuntu

EDIT: Thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for that. You set me down the right path.

For those interested in development, go here

http://www.cloudera.com/content/support/en/downloads/download-components/download-products.html?productID=F6mO278Rvo

It will save you a lot of pain.

Hadoop Video description
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o19zLaTuuSk

Comment: Thank You. This save me a ton of stress.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated if you were using vanilla Hadoop vs a distribution.  If you're using the vanilla Apache Hadoop version, you may want to try a distribution like CDH.

The [CDH5B2 Documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH5/latest/CDH5-Installation-Guide/CDH5-Installation-Guide.html) specifically addresses how to perform the installs in Ubuntu.  The distribution contains YARN, Spark, Hive, Pig, Sqoop, Flume, etc., so it should fit all of your needs.